# Extjs grid load through from submit with search parameter

Tags: extjs, grid

i have grid with large data ,i want to apply search on it with some input from a form like 
username in jon and age between 20 to 25 . this type of query pass by form .so how to load grid i am little confuse. so please suggest me .

sorry for my poor English.
thanks.

Comment: your example is right but i want to use query interface means my grid has column docs which has list of JSON documents i want to filter it on backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filterBy()` function of the grid's store on the form submit.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy

When `filterBy()` returns true that row will appear in the grid.

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/bYrMX/3/

Comment: your example is right but i want to use query interface means my grid has column docs which has list of JSON documents i want to filter it on backend.

Answer (score 1):

See if this plugin would do: [Grid MultiSearch Plugin](http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-multisearch-plugin/).